# ruby ARGF's class name weird

Tags: ruby, reflection

Is this a cruby bug?

```
km@latika:~$ ruby -v -e 'puts nil.class.to_s, ARGF.class.to_s'
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
NilClass
ARGF.class
km@latika:~$ jruby -v -e 'puts nil.class.to_s, ARGF.class.to_s'
jruby 9.3.9.0 (2.6.8) 2023-01-16 9.3.9.0+ds-8 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb12u1 on 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb12u1 +jit [x86_64-linux]
NilClass
ARGFClass
```

Nowhere else have I seen a class name containing a period...

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug, the class is explicitly created with that unusual name. From [`io.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_3_0/io.c#L15548):

```c
rb_cARGF = rb_class_new(rb_cObject);
rb_set_class_path(rb_cARGF, rb_cObject, "ARGF.class");
```

`rb_cARGF` is the class object and `rb_set_class_path` registers it under the name `"ARGF.class"`. This is only possible in C, from within Ruby such class cannot be created.

Maybe they didn't want to expose `ARGF`'s class as a regular class because it makes little sense to create another instance of `ARGF.class`. You are only supposed to interact with its pre-defined instance `ARGF`.

> Nowhere else have I seen a class name containing a period...

Note that the period isn't arbitrary, it makes the class name a valid Ruby expression: if you type `ARGF.class` it will actually resolve to the class – pretty neat.

According to the codebase, it's the only class name of that kind, but there are other examples for classes / modules having names that aren't valid constant names.

`fatal` which is a subclass of `Exception`:

```
Exception.subclasses
#=> [..., SignalException, fatal, SystemExit]
```

[`generic_readable`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/IO/generic_readable.html) and [`generic_writable`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/IO/generic_writable.html) which are defined by `StringIO` under `IO`. They are included in `StringIO`:

```
require 'stringio'

StringIO.ancestors
#=> [StringIO, IO::generic_writable, IO::generic_readable, ...]
```

Using an (otherwise) invalid constant/class name in C ensures that the object cannot be resolved as a constant in Ruby: trying `IO::generic_writable` would attempt to call it as a *method* (which doesn't exist) and `IO.const_get(:generic_writable)` raises a `NameError`.

Comment: "This is only possible in C, from within Ruby such class cannot be created" – `class Foo; def self.to_s; 'ARGF.class' end end`

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, you can conceal its actual name. But `Foo.new.inspect` for example would still reveal it. What you can't do in Ruby is something like `class "ARGF.class"; end` which would be the equivalent to the C code above.

Comment: Thanks, then according to this, it is actually a Jruby bug... isn't it 8-) actually, this is an irregularity in cruby that you may classify as non-bug, but there is probably no deep reason for it, otherwise Jruby should have followed suit. I am not saying I could fully understand your answer, but a reason for breaking the sanity expectation that a class name is actually a name, did not emerge in me. I still believe this is an old typo that was never fixed because I was the first till now (aside from JRuby developers) to actually notice it.

Comment: @marcingo it's an oddity. And given that `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, and `NilClass` exist, I have no idea why they didn't simply use `ARGFClass`.